# Fetch posts from different Facebook pages and automatically post on my web site?

Tags: php, facebook

I have to make social page for a company on their web site, i am developing web site in laravel 5.3 and i have some confusions please help me to sort out
Can i get latest posts event without login to Facebook to show on web site?
Can i get data from different pages who are created with different admin with different id's?

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use SammyK\LaravelFacebookSdk\LaravelFacebookSdk as LaravelFacebookSdk;

class GetSocialPosts extends Controller
{

    public function test (LaravelFacebookSdk $fb) {

        $page1 = $this->fb->newInstance([
          'app_id' => '134192307111971',
          'app_secret' => '2c051fcfe57fac9a52d8e82a67b2e971',
          'default_graph_version' => 'v2.8'
        ]);
        $token = 'EAACEdEose0cBABNaPI5ltuvLjiytrcCjd6ZA3kKJfOEOWGlsgdFb3b9xiZA5q46YwZA1qPVMlLZBW4ZAoWTUPzW6kqoLtZCQUC214PAeWYigJwSrMJU7ZBli4HWeCPmNqoxcxNtF5QyZAH0XfITo3VVaxkUGj8E4n14dEAv5rduJQRUwesftSgnP878ZCyVddcaoZD';
        $this->fb->setDefaultAccessToken($token);


        $response = $this->fb->get('/1201585723206526?posts');
        $response = $response->execute();
        $graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($graphObject);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this without doing anything too technical.

Have a look at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin

This plugin will show the latest posts for your client's page.

You can build the plugin and then Facebook give you two blocks of HTML - one you position just after `<body>` and the other where you want the plugin to be shown.

Comment: what if i want to use facebook graph API

Comment: can i set different APP id in one application

Comment: Yes, you could use that. Post the code you've tried so far and then somebody can give you feedback.

Comment: after running this code i have got the error "Required "app_id" key not supplied in config and could not find fallback environment variable "FACEBOOK_APP_ID""